# UBUNTU 19.10.1 Raspberry Pi 4b No Audio

Tags: sound, alsa, hdmi, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry PI 4b 4GB running UBUNTU 19.10.1 (ethernet wired/HDMI)

I have loaded the Server Version and then layered the GNOME user interface on top.  All updates have been done including firmware

From the beginning, the HDMI and on board audio did not show up.  I tried the USB Audio approach and I get Audio

I tried the raspbian operating system on the same system/setup.. the HDMP and ON board audio work...

I have tried all the various advice offered on the various user boards...  Not one (or all) allow for audio when running UBUNTU 19.10.1

Has anyone managed to get this working???

Fred

Tried Config.sys options...
Tried reinstalling the audio manager stuff
Tried the used the USB audio.. play a YOUTUBE and then while music is playing.. pull out USB
so much advice...  no solution..

Comment: you might check your mate-volume-control in MATE (mine is MATE 20.04) and check the Output Tab to see if your output is perhaps going to headphones...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
dtparam=audio=on
```

to usercfg.txt in /boot/firmware

Comment: That is a good suggestion.  I have tried it as well other options..  Sadly.. no sound

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In answer to your question, I did get sound with 19.10.1 with the MATE desktop by adding the line I suggested. I have since upgraded to 20.04 and still have sound.

Comment: Interesting...  I am not using the Mate desktop..  I am using the GNOME desktop..  It may be worth brewing up a Mate desktop to see if it makes a difference..